# Bootstrap 5 Tooltips & Slider doesnt work after Javascript .load()

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, load

my web page works the way I want it to (with Bootstrap 5), only the content I load with the load() function contains errors. I use tooltips and sliders which do not work after the load function. Before the load function everything works fine. Even if I include load(), the top section works perfectly until load(). Only after that the sliders and tooltips don't work anymore.

For understanding: The first results which are displayed on my page I load directly with PHP, the following results via .load(). I have already read that I have to include bootstrap again (after load call). I can't really get that to work for me. Would be very nice if someone could help me out.

Thank you!

My JS Script in my php-file:

```
var z = 6;
            
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                        $("#resultload"+z).load( "load.php?ca=<?php echo $kategorie; ?>&pl=<?php echo $ort; ?>&co=<?php echo $land; ?>&fi=<?php echo $filter; ?>&z="+z, function(response, status, xhr) {
                            if (response == "") { 
                                document.getElementById("loadz").style.display = "none"; 
                                document.getElementById("loadzm").style.display = "block";
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("loadz").style.display = "block"; 
                                z = z+6;
                            }
                        }); 
                   }
            });
```

Comment: Tooltips works now with: $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();. But Slider (Carousel) doesnt work.

Comment: Works with: $('[data-bs-ride="carousel"]').carousel();.